# "Today" in the context of "for today"

Tags: traducción

Consider the following sentence:

> I ate today.

It can easily translate as:

> Hoy comí.

Now consider the following:

> How much did you eat today?

In the last sentence, there's a subtle hint of "**how much did you eat for today?**" Somewhat like, say, you are on a diet and must count your calories. So the doctor asks you about your intake: "**How much today?**", "**How much was it yesterday?**". Can this context be translated with a ***por***?

> ¿Cuanto comíste por hoy?

Please let me know if you need me to explain this better. Not sure if I am being able to convey the context clearly here.

Comment: I think your "for today" is incorrect.  That changes "today" from an adverb to a noun, which means the meaning is actually changing.  "How much did you eat during class?" is quite different than "How much did you eat for the class?"  One is talking about a time (adverb) the other is talking about a purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Por hoy* is a *locución adverbial* that means "up to now" or "for the rest of the day"

```
Ya está bien por hoy
```

Translates to "Call it a day" or "this was enough for today".

```
(Por) hoy ya he comido bastante
Ya he comido bastante (por) hoy
```

In both cases you plan not to eat anythin else for today. You can use either "hoy" and "por hoy" in both sentences, they mean the same and are equally correct.

```
¿Cuánto has comido hoy?
¿Cuánto has comido por hoy?
```

In both cases he could eat more after answering the question. Although it seems both forms are correct in this case (I'm checking DRAE) and mean the same, I would never use the second form, it sounds antinatural to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "Cuánto comiste hoy?" sounds natural and it's what we use here (Venezuela).

Answer (score 1):

The context is everything in a word or phrase. If you want to use the phrase as you described it, then I would suggest, as the other two answers do, not to use "por" in it. Even when it is not incorrect, it is just not commonly used in a phrase like yours.

I must add that the original phrase is ambiguous, since when you say "how much", anyone can answer in any way they prefer, since you are not setting a baseline of how much is "a little" or how much is "a lot". Ambiguity aside, in a phrase like this, it is likely that you had a previous conversation about the intake of food. For example:

> "Your cholesterol levels are increasing, this is usually due to a high
>   intake on saturated fat for most of my patients. Out of the list I
>   provided you with food high in saturated fats, how much did you eat
>   today?"

If it is a phrase like that one, I would use the following translation for your phrase:

```
¿Cuánto comiste hoy? OR ¿Qué tanto comiste hoy?
```

Both phrases express the same idea. You can also use the word "has" (from the verb "haber"), as suggested in one of the other answers. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Cuánto has comido?
Cuánto has comido hoy?

(If it's today then you dont say in past tense)